# md-no-cache="true" efecting none

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to add auto-complete on site, i want to perform when some chips is selected it should be remove from drop-down and once its unselected it should back to the drop-down. i have read issues from git about this they said use

```
md-no-chache="true"
```

but it have no effect on auto-complete.
i will really appreciate the solution.
here is my code.

```
//HTML

<md-chips ng-model="selectedMerchants" md-autocomplete-snap="" md-transform-chip="transformChip($chip)" md-require-match="autocompleteDemoRequireMatch">
    <md-autocomplete  md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" md-no-cache="true" md-min-length="0" placeholder="Search Merchents">
        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}}  </span>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <md-chip-template>
    <span onclick="test();">
      <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
      <em>({{$chip.type}})</em>
    </span>
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>

//js
$scope.readonly = false;
$scope.selectedItem = null;
$scope.searchText = null;
$scope.querySearch = querySearch;
$scope.vegetables = loadMerchants();
$scope.selectedMerchants = [];
$scope.numberChips = [];
$scope.numberChips2 = [];
$scope.numberBuffer = '';
$scope.autocompleteDemoRequireMatch = true;
$scope.transformChip = transformChip;

function transformChip(chip) {
        // If it is an object, it's already a known chip
        if (angular.isObject(chip)) {
            return chip;
        }
        // Otherwise, create a new one
        return {name: chip, type: 'new'}
}

function querySearch(query) {
        var results = $scope.Merchants;
        return results;
}
```